# Tool to measure system uptime minus locked time from windows logs

Tags: windows, logs, system-monitor

Please let me know if you have come across a tool with this capability for Windows 7

1) read system start up and shut down times from the windows event log

2) subtract the time while the system was locked or logged off

Or if there is nothing like above, at least anything partial like parsed output of item (1) alone above, so that I can build on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want CLI, you can use the [Get-WinEvent cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849682.aspx) in [Windows PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) (free, included in     Windows XP and later):

- read system start up times: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{L
  ogname='System';ID=6005}`. Event 6005 is logged at boot time noting that the Event Log service was started. It gives the message "The Event log service was started".

[image]

- read system shut down times: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{L
  ogname='System';ID=6006}`. Event 6006 is logged as a clean shutdown. It gives the message "The Event log service was stopped".

[image]

- read system log off times: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{L
  ogname='System';ID=4634}`.

[image]

and so on.

FYI [List of all Windows 7 Event IDs and Sources?](https://superuser.com/q/394422/116475).

Answer (score 1):

Found this great tool, to get all the on/off times.
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html

[image: Screen from Owner]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI , it can simply use the [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), which is included in Windows NT and all its successors.

[Tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/160855-shut-down-view-details-last-shutdown-computer.html):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]